# In Java Eclipse, how can I move multiple icon images (button) to use action listener?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I'm struggling that how I can move multiple icons of button using action listener? I posted two screenshots and my code. Only the left icon can be moved on now. I want to move each icon alternately to forward direction. I would appreciate your consideration.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class BoardWoolf extends JFrame{

    private Container contents;
    private Object source;

    private JButton[][] squares = new JButton[8][8];
    private Color colorBlack = Color.BLACK;
    private Color colorOrange = Color.ORANGE;

    private int woolfrow1=0;
    private int woolfcol1=1;
    private int woolfrow2=0;
    private int woolfcol2=3;
    private int woolfrow3=0;
    private int woolfcol3=5;
    private int woolfrow4=0;
    private int woolfcol4=7;

    private ImageIcon woolf = new ImageIcon("wolf.PNG");

    public BoardWoolf()
    {
        super("Sheep and wolf game"); 

        contents = getContentPane();
        contents.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 8));

        ButtonHandler buttonhandler = new ButtonHandler();

        for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<8;j++)
            {
                squares[i][j] = new JButton();
                if((i+j)%2!=0) // it allows to show black blocks
                {
                    squares[i][j].setBackground(colorBlack);
                }
                else
                {
                    squares[i][j].setBackground(colorOrange);
                }
                contents.add(squares[i][j]);
                squares[i][j].addActionListener(buttonhandler);
            }
        }

        squares[woolfrow1][woolfcol1].setIcon(woolf);
        squares[woolfrow2][woolfcol2].setIcon(woolf);
        squares[woolfrow3][woolfcol3].setIcon(woolf);
        squares[woolfrow4][woolfcol4].setIcon(woolf);

        setSize(500,500);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null); //centers window
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private boolean isValidMove(int i, int j)
    {
        int rowDelta = Math.abs(i-woolfrow1);
        int colDelta = Math.abs(j-woolfcol1);

        if((rowDelta==1) && (colDelta==1))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private void processClick(int i, int j)
    {
        if(isValidMove(i,j)==false)
        {
            return;
        }
        squares[woolfrow1][woolfcol1].setIcon(null);
        squares[i][j].setIcon(woolf);
        woolfrow1 = i;
        woolfcol1 = j;

    }//01 03 05 07

private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        source = e.getSource();

        for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<8;j++)
            {

                if(source==squares[i][j])
                {
                    System.out.println("i = " +i+ "j = " +j);
                    processClick(i,j);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        new BoardWoolf();
    }
}
```

Here there are two screenshots from the application:

[image]

[image]